# Register HttpHandler under a path/folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, httphandler

Why cant i register a HttpModule under a directory?

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="/home/facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
    </httpHandlers>

  </system.web>
```

```
<handlers>
  <add name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="/home/facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
</handlers>
```

when the request comes to `/home/facebookredirect.axd` i m getting a 404. why this is not working?

I want the `facebookredirect.axd` to work under `/home/`

Below is frm, global.asx

`routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");`

Essentially. `home` doesnt exist, there is a home controller. But i want to use this path.

Comment: you dont have well-formed xml.  see system.web open tag.

Comment: @Nate it s valid. i didnt wanna copy the whole thing. just paste the closing tag. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
path="/home/facebookredirect.axd"
```

should be:

```
path="home/facebookredirect.axd"
```

Also you need to exclude this url from your routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("home/{resource}.axd");
```

Comment: ah. i was close. i had a workaround thought. thanks:) u rock!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because there is a generic .axd handler (i.e. *.axd) added before yours.

If you remove this before adding your handlers, then add it back in after your handler is added, it could resolve the problem (disclaimer: haven't tried it, just going on the evidence).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `resourceType="Unspecified"`

so it becames

```
<add name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="/home/facebookredirect.axd" 
type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web"
resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

At least, i have handlers working with folders with the same declaration.

Also folder "Home" should exists on server

Comment: "Home" deosnt have to exist on server